# How to find a TIF image with a specific color depth (8 Bit) inside a directory with 10k images?

Tags: images, image-processing

I want to find a TIF image inside a directory with a specific color depth (8 Bit) with 10'000 images. It does not need a GUI, a basic log file would be sufficient.
It should run on Windows and available for free.
I can think of some batch or powershell related solutions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This does not need powershell or anything.
Goto folder and select **Detail** view on the column heading right click and select more.
[image: Choose Details]

Select **Bit Depth** and click OK.  The **bit-depth** field will now appear.
Click on the column heading **bit-depth** and you can sort it ascending or descending there by grouping the same ones together.

Method 2:

Goto windows search on the folder in question and type:
**bitdepth:8** and hit **Enter**